# Platform Exception - User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again. (Flutter, Firebase)

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

- Implemented Google Signin - working perfectly
- User is Authenticated in Firebase - checked in firebase
- Shows User Not signed in once the user adds the certain image to the firebase storage
- Firebase Rules are public
- I don't understand how I am getting this error

**Rules To Firebase Storage**

```
rules_version = '2';

// service firebase.storage {
//   match /b/{bucket}/o {
//     match /{allPaths=**} {
//       allow read, write: if true;
//     }
//   }
// }
service firebase.storage {
  // Only a user can upload their file, but anyone can view it
  match /users/{userId}/{fileName} {
    allow read;
    allow write: if true;
  }
}
```

**Login Code**

```
Future loginUser() async {
    {
      auth.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
        if (user == null) {
          //print('User is currently signed out!');
        }
      });
      isSignedIn = true;
      final user = await gSignIn.signIn();
      if (user == null) {
        isSignedIn = false;
        return;
      } else {
        final googleAuth = await user.authentication;

        final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        );
        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        print(credential);
        isSignedIn = false;
      }
    }
    // saveUserInfoToFireStore();
    // await gSignIn
    //     .signIn()
    //     .then((gSignInAccount) => controlSignIn(gSignInAccount));
    // Navigator.push(
    //   context,
    //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
    // );
  }
```

**Compress Image**

```
String status = '';
  String imageUrl;
  bool isLoading;

  Future compressingImage() async {
    final tDirectory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tDirectory.path;
    ImD.Image mImageFile = ImD.decodeImage(eImage.readAsBytesSync());
    final compressedImageFile = File('$path/img$postId.jpg')
      ..writeAsBytesSync(ImD.encodeJpg(mImageFile, quality: 99));
    setState(() {
      eImage = compressedImageFile;
    });
  }
```

**Upload Photo to Firebase Storage**

```
Future<String> uploadPhoto(mImageFile) async {
    await gCurrentUser.authentication;
    final StorageReference reference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Event Banners");
    StorageUploadTask mStorageUploadTask =
        reference.child("post_$postId.jpg").putFile(mImageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot =
        await mStorageUploadTask.onComplete;
    String downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL(); //Getting error here
    return downloadUrl;
  }
```

**Error Received: Storage Exception:**

```
E/StorageException(13107): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(13107): User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
E/StorageException(13107):  Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
E/StorageException(13107): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(13107): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:331)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:300)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:221)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(StorageTask.java:1072)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/StorageException(13107): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:434)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:451)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:442)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:286)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:70)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:62)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:467)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:268)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:216)
E/StorageException(13107):  ... 5 more
E/StorageException(13107): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(13107): User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
E/StorageException(13107):  Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
E/StorageException(13107): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(13107): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:331)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:300)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:221)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(StorageTask.java:1072)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/StorageException(13107): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:434)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:451)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:442)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:286)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:70)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:62)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:467)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:268)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:216)
E/StorageException(13107):  ... 5 more
E/StorageException(13107): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(13107): User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
E/StorageException(13107):  Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
E/StorageException(13107): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(13107): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:331)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:300)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:221)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(StorageTask.java:1072)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/StorageException(13107): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:434)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:451)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:442)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:286)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:70)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:62)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:467)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:268)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:216)
E/StorageException(13107):  ... 5 more
E/StorageException(13107): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(13107): User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
E/StorageException(13107):  Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
E/StorageException(13107): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(13107): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:331)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:300)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:221)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(StorageTask.java:1072)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/StorageException(13107): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:434)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:451)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:442)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:286)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:70)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:62)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(UploadTask.java:467)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(UploadTask.java:268)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:216)
E/StorageException(13107):  ... 5 more
E/StorageException(13107): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(13107): User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
E/StorageException(13107):  Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
E/StorageException(13107): {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
E/StorageException(13107): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:434)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:451)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:442)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:286)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:70)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:62)
E/StorageException(13107):  at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:76)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/StorageException(13107):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](13107): windowFocusChanged hasFocus=false inTouchMode=true
W/vent_managemen(13107): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

[image: Error After Debugging]

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. After the constant work of two days, I came to know that in the debug mode, its important to **give SHA1  debug key in firebase console of your project** otherwise FirebaseStorage wouldn't allow you to upload files to Firebase storage **no matters if you have already given release SHA1 or SHA-256 keys**.

Comment: I also had to download google-services.json file again. Basically, this file contains the SHA1 hash of the key after adding it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem (in Java-Android), I enabled Firebase App Check/SafetyNet and added verification related codes to the Application class, it started working normally.

```
    if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext())
            == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        SafetyNet.getClient(this).attest((Build.DEVICE + System.currentTimeMillis()).getBytes(),
                DatabaseConstants.ADV_KEY)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        response -> Log.v("ATTEST", "SUCCESSFUL"))
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                        // An error with the Google Play services API contains some
                        // additional details.
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                        // You can retrieve the status code using the
                        // apiException.getStatusCode() method.
                        Log.v("ATTEST", "ERROR" + apiException.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                    } else {
                    }
                    Log.v("ATTEST", "ERROR");
                });

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Update Google Services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/ this);
    FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
    firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
            SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with appcheck issue. Let me share the method I run on my physical device. The issue of upload is important, the method used is important, I will share my own piece of code. Also, I think it is necessary to create a register and token in firebase, which is what I did.

appcheck safety register and manage-debug-tokens
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/usage
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/manage-debug-tokens.png

my code:

```
 Future<String> _imageUpload(File imageFile, BuildContext context) async {
    final firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
        firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;

    Random rnd = Random();
    final String imgPath =
        'imgs/${rnd.nextInt(4000)}';

    firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot tasking =
        await storage.ref(imgPath).putFile(imageFile);

//alternative 1
    String url = await storage.ref(imgPath).getDownloadURL();
    print('url1 => $url');

//alternative 2
    String url2 = await tasking.ref.getDownloadURL();
    print('url2 => $url2');

    if (url != null) {
      print('uploaded => $url');
      return url;
    }
  }
```